# Google map not loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I have tried an alternative way to load a Google map. However, I am getting 2 errors they are:

```
 //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = (zoom =8,)
 //Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined onload
```

I have highlighted the errors occurred in bold

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize()
{
    var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
        **zoom = 8,**
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps,MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
</script>

</head>

**<body onload="initialize()">**
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;">


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the 2nd error is a result of the 1st error, fix the syntax-error and initialize will be defined .

Comment: oops thankyou, such a careless mistake, infact i spotted another error by putting a comma instead dot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kammus/ux8mqabh/ enjoy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error, instead of

```
zoom = 8,
```

should be

```
zoom: 8,
```

Comment: and "mapTypeId: google.maps,MapTypeId.ROADMAP" as "mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP"

Comment: nice catch, send a review